# Pandas: max value between two running intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

Timestamp, Value, Start, End

I would like to know for each row, the maximum value based on TimeStamp >= Start & TimeStamp <= End

I cannot use rolling.max() because the start & end are not equally defined.

[image: highest]

This is some data I have.. So basically for each row I would like to find the highest High[0] row where Time[0] is between Time[0] and Time[1]

Comment: can you share some sample rows from the dataframe along with the expected result?

Comment: Time[0] will always be in the period Time[0] <= x <= Time[1] as Time[0] = Time[0]. If this isn't a mistake, then you can just get the maximum value of High[0] without any filtering

Comment: share reproducible data, not pics, along with expected output dataframe